# "Voltage source is shorted" simulation error

Tags: short-circuit, voltage-source

Take a look at the image below,

[image]

Why is that bottom voltage source is shorted? (http://everycircuit.com/app/) give me the response as voltage source is shorted, why is that?

As far as I know, If an element is shorted , two terminals of that particular element should be in  the same node, but here it does in different nodes, then how it can be a shorted one?

This is a screen-shot what (http://everycircuit.com/app/) says

[image]

Comment: It's not exactly shorted, but it's in parallel with another voltage source with a different value, which gives rise to infinite currents or more accurately undefined behavior.

Comment: But that (http://everycircuit.com/app/) says it is shorted

Comment: I hope you know that app

Comment: I don't, and it says I need the Chrome browser to run it, which I'm not going to download.  "Shorted" in my mind is different from being in parallel with another voltage source, unless maybe the other voltage source is a 0V source (i.e. an ideal wire.)

Comment: Then may I give you a screen shot of it?\

Comment: Sure, add it to your original question so we may comment on it.

Comment: The Kirchoff police will be at your door shortly. This is a 10=1 situation.

Comment: I'd imagine it says it's shorted because it's a 10V source in parallel with a 1V source. That means you have 9 volts dropped across nothing making it sort of a "short".

Comment: @  copper.hat: Then I would want to be ready to give alibis , LOL...

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess: Just be careful with charges, then.

Comment: @ copper.hat: I got a message that they return back due to some "short" in their stuffs,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because using nodal analysis and the superpostion princicple (for independent sources), you would normally analyze the circuit once source at the time, with other voltage sources shorted, and then add the results. Obviously, shorting one source also shorts the other, hence the error.
The error makes sense - the circuit cannot be analyzed as currents would be infinite. So no ideal analysis will be able to solve the circuit.

Comment: Then you are saying if we analysis  the circuit using one source at time any source would be shorted

Comment: No, using superposition you REPLACE each independent voltage source one at a time with a short and calculate the resulting node voltages. Then the final result is the sum of each of those results.  It has nothing to do with your example or an actual short across a voltage source.

Comment: Aha.. Okay , then my concept is correct , I mean this thing " If an element is shorted , two terminals of that particular element should be in the same node"

Comment: It's kind of a question of semantics.  One definition of a short circuit is: "A short circuit (sometimes abbreviated to short or s/c) is an electrical circuit that allows a current to travel along an unintended path, often where essentially no (or a very low) electrical impedance is encountered."  Under that definition the source could be considered "shorted" since the other voltage source has zero impedance.  In my definition a short is a direct connection with an ideal wire or conductor directly across two nodes.  So pick the definition you like and go with it, either way it's the same.